# Referencing a join table to a view

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, entity-relationship

I have an entity MorningMinutesNote which has a @ManyToMany relationship with MorningMinutesNoteType using a join table morning_minutes_note_item_type.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "morning_minutes_note", schema = "public")
public class MorningMinutesNote {
  private List<MorningMinutesNoteType> itemTypes = new ArrayList<MorningMinutesNoteType>();

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="morning_minutes_note_item_type",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="morning_minutes_note_id",updatable=false,insertable=false),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="item_type_id",updatable=false,insertable=false))
  public List<MorningMinutesNoteType> getItemTypes() {
    return itemTypes;
  }
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE morning_minutes_note_item_type(
  morning_minutes_note_item_type_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('morning_minutes_note_item_type_id_seq'),
  morning_minutes_note_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  item_type_id BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

I created a view table view_morning_minutes_note which uses morning_minutes_note as the main table. How can I reference the List of MorningMinutesNoteType
to the view table also so that I can also fetch the List from ViewMorningMinutesNote. I don't know if this is possible but I've tried adding the exact annotations of MorningMinutesNote
 to ViewMorningMinutesNote but it is fetching nothing.

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(selectBeforeUpdate = false,dynamicInsert = true, dynamicUpdate = true)
@Table(name = "view_morning_minutes_note", schema = "public")
public class ViewMorningMinutesNote{

  private List<MorningMinutesNoteType> itemTypes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need direct access to the `JoinTable`, you may use [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA) capability to expose the [join table for queries](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/JPA-Integration#manytomany).